# Programming a CPLD using Raspberry Pi and a JTAG HS3 cable

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, jtag

How can I program a CPLD Device (XC2C32A) when the file (.jed) is located on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ (Raspbian Lite) and the connection between the Raspberry and the CPLD Device is with a JTAG HS3 cable?

Answer (score 0):

In order to program a CPLD Device (XC2C32A) when the file (.jed) is located on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ (Raspbian Lite) and the connection between the Raspberry and the CPLD Device is with a JTAG HS3 cable, the software Adept 2 can be used.

The following is neccesary:

- Digilent JTAG-HS3 Cable
- The raspberry needs to have Adept 2 Runtime and Utilities Install (ARM - Raspberry Pi). More information in the following [link](https://reference.digilentinc.com/reference/software/adept/start?redirect=1#software_downloads)
- Connect the Device to the Raspberry pi with the JTAG Cable

Now the following python3 script can be executed:

```
import subprocess

# Read if the JTAG-HS3 is there
result = subprocess.check_output(
        ("djtgcfg enum"), 
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True).decode('utf-8')
print(result)

# Initialize chain to detect device. The -d option is used to specify the device
result = subprocess.check_output(
        ("djtgcfg init -d JtagHs3"), 
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True).decode('utf-8')
print(result)

# Erase the Device
result = subprocess.check_output(
        ("djtgcfg erase -d JtagHs3 -i 0"), 
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True).decode('utf-8')
print(result)

# Programming the Device. The -i option is used to specify the chain index and -f to specify the .jed file.
result = subprocess.check_output(
        ("djtgcfg prog -d JtagHs3 -i 0 -f myfile.jed"), 
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True).decode('utf-8')
print(result)
```